# php Undefined variable: article_id

Tags: php, undefined

I keep getting this as a warning I want to avoid getting this warning when it is undefined without turning warnings off

here is the context

```
  $url_items = array("foo");
  $article_id = db_escape($url_items[1]);
  $article = get_article($article_id);

  function get_article($article_id = NULL) {.....}
```

Comment: That is strange because `$article_id = db_escape($url_items[1]);` should assign some value to `$article_id`. I think the warning should not even occur (or it is somewhere else in your code).

Comment: hm your right didnt mention this at all... im not familiar with db_escape() does it return something at all ? or better does it always return something... hm ok just tested it a function will return null if nothing is returned so how can this function return NOTHING at all ?

Comment: PHP usually provides the file and the line number when issuing warnings. Shouldn't this be enough to find the problem?

Comment: ok gonna edit and clarify with my db_escape function altough it shouldn't matter

Comment: Add an exact copy of the error message to your edit please.

Comment: actually no it irrelevent you don't need that code,

the point is the second item is the array is NOT set therefore it us undefined Nexum answer is probably as close as I will get but was hoping for less code

Comment: This whole code is quite strange at all. it can be solved with ` if (!isset($url_items[1])) $url_items[1]="";`, yet it looks strange. Why don't you pass whole $url_items array to the function?

Comment: your if statement would do the trick i wonder why you didn't post that as an answer

Comment: @mmcgrail because it's stupid. It souldn't be at all because whole your algorithm is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm thinking that the easiest way to solve it is like this:

```
$url_items = array("foo");
$article = empty($url_items[1]) ? get_article() : get_article(db_escape($url_items[1]));

function get_article($article_id = NULL) {.....}
```

This *should* works because you give `$article_id` a default value in the function.  However, you could just as easily change the middle ternary part to null if you don't want to execute at all if there is no `$article_id`.

Edit:  If you have an article_id 0, you may want to change `empty` to `!isset`
Edit 2: Modified to avoid the undefined offset warning.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say exactly which line is causing the error, but you ought to use `isset` for any variables you are not sure exist. For example:

```
$url_items = array("foo");
if ( isset($url_items[1]) )
{
    $article_id = db_escape($url_items[1]);
    $article = get_article($article_id);
}

function get_article($article_id = NULL) {.....}
```

You'll also want to check the content of the `db_escape` method, in case that is also doing something with an undefined variable.

---

One other way around the problem is to pass the variable to the function by reference using `&`:

```
function get_article(&$article_id) {
    if ( $article_id == null ) {
        // handle null case here
    }
    else {
        // get the article
    }
}
```

Comment: ahh yes but I still need to make the call to get_article even if $article_id is not set

Comment: @mmcgrail: yeah I gave your code a try but did not get any warnings. I did get `Notice: Undefined offset: 1` though. The only time I get "Undefined variable" is if I remove the line that sets `$article_id`. Are you sure your code is the same as you posted above? Posting the content of `db_escape()` would help too.

Comment: yes your right I get that one too and I still fail to see how db_escape has anything to do with it. but that does lead me to the answer

Answer (score 0):

put this before your code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

[PHP Manual: error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: That's wrong at all, but especially in this very case. Why not E_ALL?

Comment: Ahaha, I thought you were going to help to find error, not to hide it :) It just didn't came to my mind. What a ridiculous answer from a developer.

Comment: I know how to turn on and off error reporting the point is to avoid the warning

Comment: @mmcgrail So, turn it on, read the error message and then repair it. Not a big deal, eh?

Comment: Then maybe the OP should rephrase the question from "but I don't care if its not set so how do I get rid of the warning" to "How do I fix my code".

Comment: @Iraklis It whill be same dumb question. Errors must be repaired, not gagged. OMG I have to say such basic things on the stacroverflow. unbelievable.

Answer (score 0):

so it was pretty simple after all that and yes maybe I could have phrased my question better, but it still bothers me that there is not a simpler way to do this

```
    if (isset($url_items[1])){
        $article_id = db_escape($url_items[1]);
    }else{
        $article_id = null;
    }
    $article = get_article($article_id);
```

Answer (score -1):

i think this would be a nicer way maybe there is a better way but i think just hiding the warning is the wrong way...

```
$article_id = db_escape($url_items[1]);
if(empty($article_id)){
    $article_id = null;
}
```

*edit* corrected the code

Comment: The argument to empty **must** be a variable, it doesn't work on expressions.

Comment: Powerlord is right, as it says in the docs: *Note: empty() only checks variables as anything else will result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work: empty(trim($name)).*

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is related to the error, but you should know that PHP indexes arrays starting with 0, so the second line should be

```
$article_id = db_escape($url_items[0]);
```

Also, it is probably a typo, but the first line should be

```
var $url_items = array("foo");
```

Comment: I know they start at zero the point is that

     $url_items[1];

has no value

and I don't need var in front of a variable and I'm not sure but I think that might be a problem if I did put it there